# Continuity with respect to the sets projected onto

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|)$ be the Euclidean metric space and  $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ a   convex compact set. Let

$$f(X)=\arg\min_{x\in X}\|x\|$$

Let $(X_k)_{k\geq 1}\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a sequence of  convex compact sets and $X_k\to X$ in the Hausdorff metric.

How can I show that  $f(X_k)\to f(X)$?

Thanks.

Comment: For two nonempty convex compact sets $A,B$, can you find a lower bound for $\lVert f(B)\rVert$ in terms of $\lVert f(A)\rVert$ and $d_H(A,B)$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ and $X_k$ are compact (and wlog. non-empty), it is rather simple.

**Hints:**

1. For non-empty compact sets $A,B$ we have $\max_{a\in A} d(a, B) \le \epsilon$ iff $A\subseteq B + \bar U_\epsilon$ where $\bar U_\epsilon$ is the closed ball centered at $0$ with radius $\epsilon > 0$.
2. Then, for $y_k:= f(X_k)$ and $y:=f(X)$ there exists some $x_k \in X_k$ with $\|y - x_k\| \to 0$ and $z_k\in X$ with $\| y_k - z_k \| \to 0$.
   Thus, we have
   $$ \|y\| - \|y_k - z_k\| \le \|z_k\| - \|y_k - z_k\| \le \|y_k\| \le \| y \| + \|x_k - y\| $$
   and
   $$ \lim_k \|y_k\| = \|y\|. $$
3. Assume $y_k \not\to y$. Then, there is a convergent subsequence $y_{k_n} \to \bar y \in X \setminus\{ y \}$.
4. Thus, we have $\|y\| = \lim_n \|y_{k_n}\| = \|\bar y\| > \|y\|$, a contradiction.